# Reading data from colour terrain map

Tags: image, matlab, terrain, color-mapping

I have a question about converting a height-map that is in colour into a matrix - look [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=convert%20rgb%20to%20heatmap&safe=active&biw=1920&bih=921&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMI6_76lbD7xgIVwV0UCh2muwjF#safe=active&tbm=isch&q=terrain%20map%20matlab) to see examples of such maps. If I were to have a terrain plot and plot it using `imagesc`, then I would see it as a colour map. I was wondering how I could convert an image that looks like this into its corresponding matrix.

This seems like it should be a pretty basic procedure, but I can neither work out how to do it myself nor find out how to do it online (including looking on SO).

To put it another way, the image in question is a jpeg; what I'd like is to be able to convert the .jpg file into a matrix, M say, so that `imagesc(M)`, or `surf(M)`, with the camera looking at the (x,y)-plane (from above), give the same as viewing the image, eg `imshow(imread('Picture.jpg'))`.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the RGB matrix that would be created after applying a certain `colormap` to your greyscale matrix? If so then you probably just want the [`ind2rgb`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2rgb.html) function.

Comment: Not quite actually. Let me just update.

Comment: So why not `M=imread('Picture.jpg)` then? Is your `Picture.jpg` colour or greyscale?

Comment: It's colour. That's what I'm meaning by 'colour terrain map'. If you click the link on the first line, you'll see examples. `imread` gives me an `MxNx3` matrix - an `MxN` for each colour, R, G and B - whereas I'm wanting a height-map, so **one** `MxN` matrix such that when plotted and viewed from above, it gives the same picture.

Comment: If you were to obtain a height-map from some process, then you may well export as a colour map, say 'surf() view from above'.

Comment: Then why not [`rgb2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html)? I think you need to produce some sample data. Maybe make a toy *5*-by-*5* pixel image and provide the actual input and output matrices you are looking for...

Comment: Firstly, how stupid of me: I had the documentation open for that in the Matlab help window, but I misread the first bit - I thought that it was showing two examples, but it was actually the two parts for the one example! Secondly, I'd actually got a very similar result to what you get if you don't include `colormap(map)`. Are you able to explain what that last bit does? (Perhaps make your comment into an answer, as it does answer my question, and add on that bit of information?) Thanks! :)

Comment: What do you mean by "the last bit"? Do you mean the second parameter `n`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant what does "`colormap(map)`" do, but I see that it does literally just change the colour.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Matlab's [`rbg2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html) function for this. All you need to choose is the "resolution" of the output colormap that you want, i.e. the second parameter `n`. So if you specify `n` as `8` for example, then your colormap will only have `8` values and your output indexed image should only have `8` values as well.

Comment: Excellent. So I can change it to `rgb2ind(RGB,64)`, and this just gives me finer detail.

Comment: @SmileySam correct. There are also different dithering algorithms (i.e. how it lowers the *colour* resolution) and different algorithms for how it maps the intensities i.e. uniform or minimum variance. The docs (linked in answer) explain the differences.

Comment: If I apply `colormap(map)`, then the images look the same, but I still don't have the actual height-data matrix yet. `IND` isn't right because that's just going from 0-64 (or 0-63?). I don't a height-map that changes height when I change how fine the detail/resolution is...

Comment: I'm starting to think that maybe it's not actually possible to do what I'm looking for, because you can always change the colour schemes anyway so it's not a completely well-defined concept...?

Comment: I am not sure if this is very mathematically accurate. `rgb2ind` will try to find the n most different colours in the image, but unless the colormap is defined in the same way the result will not be very good at segmenting (unless a very high number of `n` are chosen). Basically, with the `jet` colormap, you can get `n` different heights, but the real "altitude" range of each of the `n` index will be totally different!! This is very important if the data means to be accurate.

Comment: Unless, of course, the map is plotted like this: http://www.eos.ubc.ca/~rich/private/extbase.gif

Comment: Ah, I think I see. The data isn't plotted like your example; it's plotted like this: http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/wiki/Research/altrep/newtile7orig.jpg

Comment: I think I may have accepted the answer slightly prematurely. I haven't actually been able to use Dan's answer to get the solution that I desire...

Comment: @SmileySam that's quite different from what you were asking though because there appears to be some sort of binary mask (distinct dark and light areas) with the height map (colours) overlaid... The mask makes this problem potentially a lot more complex

Comment: Ok yeah, I now see what you mean. I was also trying it with this: http://i.imgur.com/S7C4w.jpg. That one is perhaps more usable. All I'm really looking for is a reasonably varying terrain data, but one that I can plot and use the surf viewing tools on.

Comment: @SmileySam If you have data like the pictures you are showing, you wont find a good way of getting the real data. In the first picture there is a "binary mask" over the map. In t he second one, there are shades and light reflection. In both cases, a single altitude will have different RGB values.

Comment: @SmileySam are you just looking for sample data?

Comment: @AnderBiguri - good point, I hadn't noticed that. Definitely not going to get proper data from that.

Comment: @Dan - basically, yeah. But I wanted interesting terrain data, that I could then manipulate. Also, I wanted to be able to see my initial data. I've got some interesting terrain data, but it's all wrapped modulo 2\pi - my program then unwraps it to get back the original data, and I wanted some data that I could check my program with.

Comment: Apologies that, in the end, it's all been rather futile.

Comment: @SmileySam if you just want terrain data, why not try a site like http://terrain.party/ ? If you really want it coloured then apply the colour map in Matlab and save it as an RGB image (but I doubt you'll want to do that since this gives you the data directly)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the color coding scheme used, you might try first converting the RGB values to [HSL or HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and using the hue values for the terrain heights.